# Appending a new value to python list

Tags: python, list

```
aList = []    
for number in range (1,11):    
    aList += [number]    
print ("printing",aList);
```

Output is:
 printing 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

but if I modify like this (I expect 100 to be added to the end of the list)

```
aList = []    
for number in range (1,11):
    aList += [number]    
aList += 100;    
print ("printing",aList);
```

I get this error: **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

Comment: i think this is the way:     aList.append(100);

Comment: @Daenarys When you improve  the markup of a code block, please keep the relative indentation correct. In Python that indentation is significant.

Comment: Sorry for the initial comment that your code would not run because of indentation problems, that was result of Daenarys incorrect and incomplete suggested edit, which [was approved](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7623992)  by [Tay2510](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2995038/tay2510), [Yunus Nedim Mehel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/936957/yunus-nedim-mehel) and [Stefan Hanke](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1262542/stefan-hanke) without any of those three noticing the introduced error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `.append()` on a list:

```
aList = []    
for number in range (1,11):
    aList += [number]    
aList += [100]    
print ("printing",aList)
```

Please note that you don't need the semicolon at the end of the line (`;`)

Comment: I think `aList += [100]` should be outside the for loop.  Your code causes the output to be [1, 100, 2, 100, 3, ...]

Comment: @AndrewFarber You're absolute right. I did not pay attention while correcting the question (which was completely unindented), and copied the error.

Answer (score 3):

You have three problems with your current code:

1. `aList += 100` should be `aList += [100]`
2. You should remove all of the semicolons
3. `aList += [100]` should be moved to outside the for loop

For example:

In [2]:

```
aList = []    
for number in range (1,11):
    aList += [number]    
aList += [100]    
print ("printing",aList)  #  ('printing', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 100])
```

You could also simply this to:

```
print ("printing", range(1, 11) + [100]) # ('printing', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 100])
```

Answer (score 1):

range returns a list, hence this much is sufficient instead of for loop

```
aList = range(1, 11)
```

to add '100' as last element, add one more statement

```
aList += [100]
```

or

```
aList.append(100)
```

Answer (score -1):

`range` is a list. Hence, you can just do:

```
aList = range(10) + [100]
```

Comment: That gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'list'` because `type range((10))` gives `<class 'range'>`. Since the OP uses print function (and not statement) as well as range instead of xrange, you should probably assume he is using Python3.X

Comment: It may not work on Python 3.x, but that's because Python 3.x uses iterators for everything. Its relatively easy to just change the above statement to `aList = list(range(10)) + [100]` for Python 3.x

Comment: thanks so much guys; simply adding [] solved the problem